# How to update .complete() for compatibility with jQuery 3 (works with jQuery 1.9)

Tags: jquery

I’ve found a jQuery plugin that suits my need. However, it was made to work with jQuery 1.9 and I need to use jQuery 3.

I’ve found the issue but I’m not sure how to update it to jQuery 3.

Here is the issue :

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){

    // code that works

}).complete(function(){

    // code that works

}); // END getJSON
```

The issue is with `.complete()` :

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near
>   '...}).complete(function(){...')

If I remove it :

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){

// code that works

});

// code that works
```

The plugin works wih jQuery 3.

How To update `.complete()` for compatibility with jQuery 3 ?

Here is the complete JS : https://github.com/spidoche/spidocheTube/blob/master/jquery.spidochetube.js

Comment: When do you want the logic to happen?  Good case, bad case, or always?

Comment: @Taplar always, when the datas are retrieved, it’s complete and then other code as to be executed.

Comment: Then you should be able to use `always` ( http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/ ) if you want the code to happen regardless of if the request was resolved or rejected.

Comment: @Taplar It’s a simple jQuery youtube gallery plugin. What the code is supposed to do : When the JSON request is complete, then Initialize the first video. I check "always". Here is the complete JS : https://github.com/spidoche/spidocheTube/blob/master/jquery.spidochetube.js

Comment: @Taplar No more issue with `always`. But it should be "When the JSON request is complete, then execute some code". Is it clear?

Comment: I'm still slightly confused.  So are you saying you do not want it to happen if the request rejects, and only if it resolves?

Comment: @Taplar yes, you're right. I was unclear. The plugin doesn’t handle the case   if the request is rejected. The `complete()` is here to execute code after the request is done. Perhaps you can have a look at the github link. It would be easiest to understand.

Comment: I'm just trying to get a grasp on when you want it to happen.  If you want it to happen always, you can use `complete()`.  If you want it to only happen on the good case, then you can use `then()` or `done()`.  If you want it to only happen on the bad case, you can `fail()` or use `then()` and pass the function in as the second argument.  You can review the various deferred callbacks available on the api. (Ref. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ )

Comment: @Taplar `then()` should be ok. I don’t know why `complete()` doesn’t work in this case. You say it should work with jQuery 3, it is not deprecated ?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `always()`, not `complete()` in my last comment.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you for clarifying that. You should post your last comment. I will up vote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to happen always, you can use `always(function)`. If you want it to only happen on the good case, then you can use `then(function)` or `done(function)`. If you want it to only happen on the bad case, you can `fail(function)` or use `then(null, function)`. You can review the various deferred callbacks available on the api. (Ref. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object )